# Sscanf Not Working As I Though It Would

Tags: c, scanf

I am using sscanf to parse output of an AT command.

The command output is

```
<CR><LF>+CCLK: "17/12/03,14:12:26+22"<CR><LF>
```

The code I am using to extract the date & time values is

```
sscanf((const char*)s_last_incoming_string, "%*c%*c+CCLK:%*c\"%u/%u/%u,%u:%u:%u%d\"%*c%*c", &s_last_network_time.year, &s_last_network_time.month, &s_last_network_time.day_of_month, &s_last_network_time.hour, &s_last_network_time.minute,  &s_last_network_time.second,&temp);
```

However the parsed values I get are

```
0 0 3 0 0 26
```

Only the date and second field is getting parsed. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The first `<CR><LF>` will be with the line above if this is a file?? Does removing the 1st `%*c%*c` make it work?

Comment: It's not a file. The buffer s_last_incoming_string contains the output along with the cr lf pair

Comment: Ok, but be aware some OS and some toolkits treat `CRLF` as a single-character (e.g. GTK+, etc..). Try one `%*c` in that case. (I have a bug open with GTK+ on that very issue)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Good to keep in mind. This however is running on a bare metal avr

Comment: Use, e.g. `char *p = s_last_incoming_string; while (*p && isspace(*p)) p++; size_t off1 = p - s_last_incoming_string; while (*p) p++; p--; while (p > s_last_incoming_string) *p-- = 0; p = s_last_incoming_string + off1; `sscanf (p, +CCLK:%*c\"%u/%u/%u,%u:%u:%u%d\"%*c%*c", ...`

Comment: Check the types of `s_last_network_time.year` et al and make sure they are all `unsigned int` or at least `int`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you! You nailed it. At some point I had changed my time structure to use uint8_t to save space and completely forgot about it. If you could add this as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: `\"%*c%*c` -- there is no need for this at the end of the format string since `sscanf()` is being used, i.e. no need to consume trailing characters when scanning a buffer.

Comment: Got it. I only added it for the sake of completeness